# GetFeature WFS request with Spatial Filter throws error

Tags: wfs, mapserver, getfeature

I'm using the following request in order to get the closest feature from a layer given some specific coordinates:

```
http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012/wfs?&VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=MSPF_POLY&Filter=<Filter><DWithin><PropertyName>msGeometry</PropertyName><gml:Point<gml:coordinates>158380,4130457</gml:coordinates></gml:Point><Distance units='m'>10000</Distance></DWithin></Filter>
```

But the result is:

mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.

I also have tried with the following example of the documentation a the result is the same:

```
https://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wfs?&VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WFS
  &REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=cities&Filter=<Filter>
  <DWithin><PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName><gml:Point>
  <gml:coordinates>135.500000,34.666667</gml:coordinates>
  </gml:Point><Distance units='m'>10000</Distance></DWithin></Filter>
```

Comment: Does the documentation have the incorrect syntax `wfs?&` should be `wfs?`  the `&` is at the end of the parameter key[=value]&

Comment: Assuming `<gml:Point<gml:coordinates>` is a transcription error and not what you tried?  Should be `<gml:Point><gml:coordinates>`

Answer (score 2):

The Filter elements are missing the correct namespace prefix, in this case `ogc` which you can determine from the GetCapabilities response:

> http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0&

```
<WFS_Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" updateSequence="0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-capabilities.xsd">
...

<ogc:Filter_Capabilities>
    <ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
        <ogc:Spatial_Operators>
            <ogc:Equals/>
            <ogc:Disjoint/>
            <ogc:Touches/>
            <ogc:Within/>
            <ogc:Overlaps/>
            <ogc:Crosses/>
            <ogc:Intersect/>
            <ogc:Contains/>
            <ogc:DWithin/>
            <ogc:BBOX/>
        </ogc:Spatial_Operators>
    </ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
    <ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
        <ogc:Logical_Operators/>
        <ogc:Comparison_Operators>
            <ogc:Simple_Comparisons/>
                <ogc:Like/>
                <ogc:Between/>
            </ogc:Comparison_Operators>
    </ogc:Scalar_Capabilities>
</ogc:Filter_Capabilities>
```

Elements without a prefix take on the default namespace (http://www.opengis.net/wfs).

I made some changes to the request and I get a correct response.

```
http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/medioambiente/mapwms/REDIAM_PPHH_2012/wfs?VERSION=1.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:MSPF_POLY&Filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:DWithin><ogc:PropertyName>msGeometry</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Point><gml:coordinates>454124,4084277</gml:coordinates></gml:Point><ogc:Distance units="m">2500</ogc:Distance></ogc:DWithin></ogc:Filter>
```

Response:

[image]

Comment: That endpoint seem broken now. Any new one?